# How can I overlay a banner/status line on every web page in a test environment

Tags: html, css, apache

I have a "testing" environment setup and cloned from our production servers. I'm trying to figure out a simple way to visually indicate to anyone that they are proxied into the test environment and not production (and vice versa). I started modifying our company logos in "test" by overlaying them with, well, the word "TEST" but there are a lot of logos.. besides, anytime we clone production back into testing to refresh things, all those logos need to be moved back.  It's just a greasy way of doing things.

Anyone know of a way to configure Apache to inject or overlay a one line status at the top or bottom of the browser? Ideally, this would be unaffected by any AJAX, javascript or CSS code running in the application.

Answer (score 1):

My company does it by including a stylesheet that puts an image banner accross the top that says "development mode"

Here's the CSS we use (`development.css`)

```
@CHARSET "UTF-8";
body{
    background-image:url('/images/intra/development.png');
    background-position:top center;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    margin-top:26px !important;
}
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Apache's [mod_ext_filter](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_ext_filter.html)

```
ExtFilterDefine addhtml mode=output intype=text/html cmd="/bin/sed s/$/<div>Additional content</div>/g"
```

This will add `<div>Addition content</div>` code to the end of any `text/html` response.

Comment: Nice! Sorta works. Some of the content is served using gzip compression. Will this configuration inadvertently affect that output?

Comment: This depends on how apache calls modules, but I think, this should work.